# Range slider and labels disappear

Tags: html, css, range, bootstrap-slider

When I change the style of my input, the labels and the value of the cursor disappear...
I don't know what's the matter...
Before :
[image]

Then, now that I changed the style :

[image]

The code :

```css
 #slidecontainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #afe0fc;
  padding: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
    }
  /* Styling the slider background */
  #range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: grey;
  outline: none;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  width:100%; 
  }
  
  /* Styling the thumb */
  #range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #078dd8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  }
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="slidecontainer">
    <input
      id="range"
      type="range"
      data-slider-ticks="[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]"
      data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="10"
      data-slider-ticks-labels='["0€", "100€", "200€", "300€", "400€", "500€"]'
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any explanations or help

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are including the bootstrap-slider namespace if not using jQuery.
"**data-provide="slider"**

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="slidecontainer">
    <input
      id="range"
      type="range"
      data-provide="slider"
      data-slider-ticks="[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]"
      data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="10"
      data-slider-ticks-labels='["0€", "100€", "200€", "300€", "400€", "500€"]'
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

with jQuery:

```
$('#slidecontainer input').slider();
```

without JQuery

```
var slider = new Slider('#slidecontainer input', {});
```

further examples found: https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/#example-13

Comment: it's like when I use the style the labels go away... it comes back without script... (I answered to show you)